# sed to remove character pattern from end of line?

Tags: regex, sed

I've seen several examples on here of something close to what I'm asking, but not quite.

I have some pipe-delimited flat files which have some extraneous column data that I want to strip out using sed.  the basic structure looks like this:

```
Column1|Column2|Column3|ignore
data1|data2|data3|ignore
data4|data5|data6|ignore
```

I want an expression using sed that will produce:

```
Column1|Column2|Column3
data1|data2|data3
data4|data5|data6
```

This should be stupid easy, but as always regular expressions and sed manage to hurt my brain.  I thought this would work:

```
sed "s/\|ignore//" table1.txt >filtered.txt
```

but this seems to do nothing.  What am I doing wrong?

*NOTE:  This is GNU sed for Windows.*

Comment: In addition to the solutions below, anchor your pattern: `/|ignore$/`. That way it will not inadvertantly match in the middle of a line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't escape the pipe.

```
$ sed 's/|ignore//' table1.txt > filtered.txt
```

works on my machine. (GNU sed on Cygwin.)

The idea here is that `\|` is the regex pipe, not the literal pipe. I don't quite know how to figure these things out, but to use `(`, `{`, or `|` in sed regex, you must escape them. But `[` is not escaped, unless you want the literal character.

Comment: Hah!  I knew it was something stupid and simple.  That worked.

Comment: @JoshLee Thanks, that's useful. But what does `7 regex` mean?

Comment: @EricWilson `7` is the `Miscellaneous` category of manual pages.

Answer (score 3):

Change `\|` to `|`. You don’t want an alternative, you want a literal pipe.

Or, if you use `\|`, pass `-r` to sed to indicate you want the extended syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Several possible solutions [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/removing-columns-from-a-file-using-%60sed%60-586872/). Also, why not use cut?

Comment: If you are not referring to the cut and paste stuff in Windows, all I can say is I've never heard of that utility.  Bear in mind I am on Windows.

Comment: Apologies - since you got sed for windows I assumed you also got all the other unix-y text utils. [link](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)